# Generating CSV from CMS EditForm

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a project where people can book places on events. There are dozens of events. I have been requested to generate a report listing attendees so they can be checked in at the door. Because there are so many events, I would like to add an "Attendees Report" button to the editform for each event (inside the CMS). I have created the button, and it works.

BUT... instead of getting the data in a CSV, I get the (correct) data displaying in the CMS, as if it was being echoed.

Here is my function

public function getCustomersForEvent($data, $form){

```
    $attendees = CustomerOrderLine::get()->filter(array("EventID" => $data["ID"]));

    if(!$attendees){
        return false;
    }

    $fileName = "report.csv";

    $separator = ",";
    $csvColumns = array("ID", "Description", "Customer");

    $fileData = "";

    foreach($attendees as $row){
        $fileData .= $row->Event()->EventName . $separator;
        $fileData .= $row->CustomerOrder()->Customer()->FirstName . " " . $row->CustomerOrder()->Customer()->Surname . "\n";
    }

    return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file($fileData, $fileName, 'text/csv');
}
```

I have had a look at this http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/15325 but the data echoed to the CMS anyway.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? As I said, the data is fine, but I'm not getting the CSV Open or Save dialog.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set a content disposition header before sending the output

Comment: .
.
nope, it still outputs as text on the CMS.

Answer (score 2):

The solution will be in how you are calling this.  I would advise that you make a complete new controller or modify a module like...

https://github.com/axyr/silverstripe-phpexcel

...where you can copy the php code and modify it to return just the data you require from above.

To make a controller that is only focused on downloading a file...

```
class CustomersForEvent_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array (
        'downloadcsv',
    );

    public function downloadcsv() {
        return SS_HTTPRequest::send_file("my content",'myfile.csv','text/csv');
    }

}
```

and add that controller to the routes in _config/config.yml...

```
Director:
  rules:
    'attendees': 'CustomersForEvent_Controller'
```

...and then you can just link to yousite.com/attendees/downloadcsv

This has been tested locally and confirmed to work

Comment: It will work inside the CMS?

I will have a look at that. In the meantime, I sort of got around the problem by saving things to a file (one per each Member that generates report) and then returning a sprintf link to the file. 

But it's as ugly as home made sin so I will look at your answer.

Comment: yes both solutions "work in the CMS" but in different way - the module shows how to adjust / make a button for this.  The custom controller is designed so that you can make a link (with target = "_blank") to it and that triggers the download for basically the same UX

Answer (score 0):

Is this report to be generated from within the CMS itself? If so, do you have a `ModelAdmin` for managing `CustomerOrderLine` objects? If so, can you not use the GridField's "Export to CSV" button?

In order to output anything more than just those fields displayed by the GridField itself, you'll need to create/alter your model class's `$getExportFields()` method to return an array of all the fields on your model you wish to be exported in this manner.

Comment: Yes, it's to be generated inside the CMS and yes, I do have a working ModelAdmin. 

The reason why I don't think I can use the GridFieldExportButton is because I am trying to get a list of people attending *an* event, not the whole list.

So the user would go into ModelAdmin, select a record, and the button is on the EditForm. 

I can generate a CSV report, but I can't seem to get the usual "open or save" dialogue.

Comment: Odd about the non-appearance of the save dialogue. If you wanted to explore why, look at the browser headers sent buy the websever and your browser tools.

Aside from that, I see what you're trying to do - you want an export button for _each GridField row_ right?

It's a matter of creating a new implementation of `GridField_ActionProvider`. Take a look at one I did for the advancedworkflow module a couple of years ago. Looks like it should do pretty much what you need? https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/advancedworkflow/blob/master/code/forms/gridfield/GridFieldExportAction.php